# What does a repository look like when using many 1:Many or Many:Many tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, orm, entity-framework-4.1, repository

I have a MVC application that uses that entity framework model object directly in the view. I'm not sure how bad of a design pattern this is, but [based on this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457899) I need to use a repository to implement caching.

```
namespace MVCAzureStore.Services.Caching
{
    public class CachedProductsRepository : CachedDataSource, IProductRepository
    {
        private readonly IProductRepository repository;

        public CachedProductsRepository(IProductRepository repository, ObjectCache cacheProvider) :
            base(cacheProvider, "Products")
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public List<string> GetProducts()
        {
            return RetrieveCachedData(
                "allproducts",  () => this.repository.GetProducts(),
                new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1) });
        }
    }
}
```

Since this view uses the navigation properties of the EF I need to replicate this notion(or have something similar in mine).

**Question**

> How should I construct my repository when handling many tables that have a 1:Many or Many:Many relationship?

Any code sample, article, or more info would be appreciated, since I learn best that way

Comment: "I'm not sure how bad of a design pattern this is" - it's very bad

Comment: It's not a great pattern, but it's not a huge issue to change. When I've seen it implemented I don't recommend an immediate change, but instead advise that when it stops working (which it will) then should move to more standard MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

All you should have to do is make sure `repository.GetProducts()` eagerly loads the appropriate navigation properties.

Comment: I'm still not sure what to return in place of `List<string>`.  Can I return the EF ORM Model? Can I return `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` based on Linq? Should I create a new ViewModel?

Comment: @makerofthings7: It would probably be best to return an `IEnumerable<Product>` (which would actually be a `List<Product>` in its implementation). But if you want to avoid using ORM objects in the front-end you could come up with a DTO that just has the data you're actually looking for. As Nazar says, you'd want to have a separate repository interface specifically for producing those DTOs. If you want an actual ViewModel based on this data, that should probably be produced by your controller rather than the repository.

Answer (score 1):

See the repository in this tutorial, which allows you to specify eager loading for specified navigation properties:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the repository is created for each business object. But this raises the problem of object loading which will not be done in case when lazy loading is disabled.